# I have trigger and i have written test class for this its showing 46% how do cover the test coverage

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

```
trigger creatingMenuDetails on Opportunities__c (after insert,after update) {
      list<Menu_Detail__c> MD=new list<Menu_Detail__c>();
      for(Opportunities__c op:trigger.new)
      {
           list<Menu_Detail__c> MD1=[select id,Food__c,Amount_Per_Head__c,Activity_Name__c,Description__c,Objective_Category__c,Props_Min_No_Of_Persons__c,name,Opportunity__c from Menu_Detail__c where Opportunity__c=:op.id ];
           list<Package__c> pd=[select id,Activity_Name__c,Food__c,Amount_With_Service_Tax__c,Stay__c,name,Amount__c from Package__c where Package_Detail__c=:op.Package_Detail__c];

           if(MD1.size()==0)
           {
                for(integer i=0;i<pd.size();i++)
                {

                   Menu_Detail__c om=new Menu_Detail__c();
                   om.Opportunity__c=op.id;
                   om.name=pd[i].name;
                   om.Activity_Name1__c=pd[i].Activity_Name__c;
                   om.Amount_Per_Head__c=pd[i].Amount_With_Service_Tax__c;
                   om.Stay__c=pd[i].Stay__c;
                   om.Food__c=pd[i].Food__c;
                   MD.add(om);
                }
           }
       }
       insert MD;
}



Test Class:


@istest
public class MenuUpdate
{
    public static testmethod void Menu()
    {
        Package_Detail__c Pac = new Package_Detail__c();
        Pac.Name='test3';       
        insert Pac;   

        Opportunities__c Opp=new Opportunities__c();
        Opp.Name='test1';
        Opp.Package_Detail__c=Pac.id;
        insert opp; 

      Menu_Detail__c Men1=new Menu_Detail__c();
        Men1.name='test2';
        Men1.Opportunity__c=opp.id;
        insert Men1;

        Package__c p = new Package__c();
        p.name='tegysdg';
        p.Package_Detail__c =Opp.Package_Detail__c;
        insert p;

        Menu_Detail__c Men=new Menu_Detail__c();
        Men.name='test2';
        Men.Opportunity__c=opp.id;
        insert Men;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, before even looking at test coverage you have some issue with SOQL queries inside a for loop. You will run into limits very fast. Is the Package__c object linked to the opportunity? how many products are their? Do you set the package on the opportunity first? I will then help you with your test coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mihai's comment above is correct - this code has some issues. The actual reason you cannot get coverage for this trigger is here that you assigned a Menu_Detail__c record to your Opportunity in the test class:

```
  Menu_Detail__c Men1=new Menu_Detail__c();
    Men1.name='test2';
    Men1.Opportunity__c=opp.id;
    insert Men1;
```

But you have a check in the trigger to only run the inner loop if the MD1.size() == 0:

```
       if(MD1.size()==0)
```

which means that the test class never executes the inner loop of the trigger.